# как взять аргументы у функции input в python3.9?

Tags: python

как мне парсить аргументы из функции input?
например если пользователь написал в input: command -h или --help
как сделать так чтобы программа видела эти аргументы?
или example --link stackoverflow.com
просто я очень давно думаю и везде все прогуглил
помогите пажалуйста, заранее спасибо

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html

Comment: @MaxU а возможно вообще это сделать с input?

Comment: я просто я знаком с этой статьей и там сказано не о input

Comment: Посмотрите как это реализовано в исходниках `argparse` и переделайте под себя ;)

Comment: ладно, спасибо я попробую.

Comment: функция `input()` предназначена для чтения введённой пользователем информации во время работы программы. аргументы же программе передаются при её запуске (т.е. ещё до начала работы программы) операционной системой. для разбора аргументов можно воспользоваться, например, https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 0):

В [другом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1252352/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-3-x/1252464#1252464) я сделал [fargparser](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/a14V/YpYKw1NLk) парсер аргументов. Можно использовать его как пример.

```
arguments = input("Arguments: ")# GetArgsStr()
#print("Command line: \"" + arguments + "\"")
parser = FParser(arguments)
print(parser.result)
```

Comment: эта библиотека может читать аргументы после комманды в input() ?

Comment: В этом ее суть. Я привел пример этого в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо, все понял.

Comment: можно еще вы ответите куда архив распаковать на линуксе чтобы библиотека работала?

Comment: у меня kali linux 2020.04 gnome

Comment: а точнее 2021.01